# Generic Method Java

Tags: java, generics

I need use this method with three distinct classes: Orders, Customers, Suppliers

```
public void saveObjectKey(String filename, Long start) {
    Query<Orders> query = datastore.createQuery(Orders.class)
            .field("O_ORDERKEY").greaterThan(start);
    for (Orders orders : query.fetch()) {
        Util.writeFile(orders.getPrimaryKey().toString(), filename);
    }
}
```

I had thought in an ugly solution, a if else if solution:

if(instanceof Orders)....
else if(instanceof Customers).....
else if(instanceof Suppliers)....

Now i need a generic solution, how can i do it?

Comment: What is this method supposed to do?  And how does it interact with those classes?

Comment: You are right, a bunch of instanceof's suggest a bad design. Why not have all three classes implement the same interface, and then call the interface method(s) in this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can this make sense in your application:

```
public <T> void saveObjectKey(String filename, Long start, Class<T> clazz, String keyName) {
    Query<T> query = datastore.createQuery(clazz).field(keyName).greaterThan(start);
    for (T o : query.fetch()) {
        Util.writeFile(o.getPrimaryKey().toString(), filename);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
saveObjectKey(filename, start, Customers.class, customersKeyName);
saveObjectKey(filename, start, Suppliers.class, suppliersKeyName);
saveObjectKey(filename, start, Orders.class, ordersKeyName);
```

Comment: Thanks nobeh, it was im looking for.
One more doubt,
o.getPrimaryKey() isn't reconized. Some tip for me?

Comment: I believe `query.fetch()` gives you a `Collection<SOMETHING>` in which `SOMETHING` has the method `getPrimaryKey()`. You should cast `T o` inside the loop to `SOMETHING` to be able to receive the method.